# regex working in egrep, but not in sed

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, grep

I'm trying to identify the country abbreviations in a text.

```
egrep "^[A-Z]{2}$" file
```

seems to work. But when I'm trying the regex on sed, it's not working. This is what I'm using

```
sed 's/^[A-Z]{2}$/someCountry/' file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add a `/` before last `'` and add a `^` after first `'` and use sed's option `-E`.

Comment: -E seemed to be the problem. Thanks

Comment: On some systems the extended regular expressions `sed` flag is either `-r` or `-E` on my system both `-E` and `-r` exist yet only `-r` is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man sed` and search for "extended". `egrep` is `grep` with a flag (`-e` on some platforms) for 'extended' regexes, and sed has a similar flag. Otherwise the syntax is different and you have to use `\` a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX `sed` uses **BREs** (*basic regular expressions*).  In those, you can use the equivalent of `{2}`, but you must *escape* the *braces*.  `egrep` supports **EREs** (*extended regular expressions*).  As a side-effect of extending the BREs, the rules for escaping are different (to make the resulting expressions simpler to write).

For reference:

- [sed - stream editor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html)
- [Regular Expressions in sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02)
- [9.3 Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03)

> When a BRE matching a single character, a subexpression, or a back-reference is followed by an interval expression of the format `"\{m\}"`, `"\{m,\}"`, or `"\{m,n\}"`, together with that interval expression it shall match what repeated consecutive occurrences of the BRE would match. The values of *m* and *n* are decimal integers in the range `0 <= m<= n<= {RE_DUP_MAX`}, where *m* specifies the exact or minimum number of occurrences and *n* specifies the maximum number of occurrences. The expression `"\{m\}"` shall match exactly *m* occurrences of the preceding BRE, `"\{m,\}"` shall match at least m occurrences, and `"\{m,n\}"` shall match any number of occurrences between *m* and *n*, inclusive.